# how do i do that: Visual Studio shows no error description

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

first of all i dont know what the title error wants from me therefore its this strange title for the problem xD

If I purposely mistype "Count" into "cont", I have an Error or Suggestion from VS that doesn't show any description.

[image: see image]

But if i press the 'play' button i can see the error Description in the error window.

[image: see image]

I have reinstalled VS and checked all Variables in Unity.
I have no idea whats the problem and i dont know what to search for. Cause the intellisense system works and it shows that there is an error at the line but not the error description :/

- Red

(What did you try and what were you expecting?)
i dont know what to write here?! i say everything in the other input box

Comment: It says `upgrades` variable has no field named `cont`, try type `upgrades.Count` instead

Comment: `.Count`, not `.cont`

Comment: i know that is .count.
i created that error to show the problem i meant

Comment: I personally use Rider by JetBrains with the Unity package installed, which is much better than Visual Studio. If you are a student, you can get it for free, otherwise you need a subscription for it, but if you are taking programming professionally, I totally recommend it.

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` folder and rebuilding. This happens if the intelisense cache is corrupted.

Comment: Are you logged on in the visual studio with your account? I could not see any suggestions when i was logged out. I am not sure if this is the same case with you.

Comment: First of all you need to check if there are method definitions used in the corresponding class. If this method exists in the class, the .BLL and .DAL files need to be regenerated at this time.

Comment: Hi, have you checked my answer, does it work on your side? :)

Comment: You can also consider reset the settings of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, after re-install VS the issue still exists, so the issue should come from the project level cache/settings instead of VS environment file lacking.

You can try to create a new project and writing your code as the simplest like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Upgrade> upgrades = new List<Upgrade>();
            var xxx = upgrades.cont;
        }
    }
    class Upgrade
    {
    }
}
```

If the issue disappears in the new project, I suggest you delete '.vs' directory, '.vs' directory stores settings and caches, it will be created when you open the solution at the first time. This directory is under the same folder level of .sln file. After deleting it, when you open the solution next time, this directory will be re-generated. Intellisense caches are in this directory, that's why we suggest you to re-generate it.

If the issue doesn't disappear in the new project, please check your VS version, if it is not the lastest, please update it to the latest version.